# Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer, require

I am using Composer, but nothing I have tried has worked.

I tried require composer autoload.

```
require BASE_URL.'assets/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and use the namespace

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

but I still receiving a Error message

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in

Here is my simplified class

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
class Email extends model{ 
    public function enviarContato($nome, $email, $mensagem){
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
}
}
```

I believe that i am importing wrong, so here is my path structure.

[image: img]

[image: img]

I'm using Email.php.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried including PHP Mailer without using composer ?

Comment: Why is all of this composer stuff in what looks like a a public folder (even though it's named assets)? It should be in your project root.

Comment: @JonStirling should I have installed out of assets?

Comment: @JuanJ Yes, don't work, i think maybe have install composer wrong

Comment: download PHP Mailer and put them in PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer. You will not see this message.

Comment: @UmarAbdullah I already download PHP Mailer using composer

Comment: have check path is correct for the PHPMailer.

Comment: I'm confused with the `BASE_URL` constant. Does it really contain a URL? The `require` call cannot work unless you feed it with a file system path.

Comment: @JonStirling I edit the post, now vendor is in root path

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález BASE_URL contain http://192.168.1.240/project/ is the same link i use to acess from my smartphone

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha it shouldn't contain an URL it should contain file path to the root of your projects, also I don't think vendor is inside assets directory

Comment: You could also very likely have a path problem in your app. Check the path to vendor/autoload such as in Constants.php file, or the relevant location based on your setup/framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BASE_URL contain `http://192.168.1.240/project/`

If you feed `require` with a URL the whole call happens through the web server, thus you get the result of code execution rather than code itself. You need a file system path, e.g.:

```
require __DIR__ . '/path/to/autoload.php';
```

Comment: i had to use :
 require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\Exception.php';

But it worked well, thanks!

Comment: Er... You need to require Composer's `autoload.php`.

Comment: Worked!!! `require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'\vendor\autoload.php';`

Comment: Or `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` (it should be the same).

Comment: I just came across this, and this indeed was my problem too, thanks for that! Can you may explain that further, or may tell me where I can find the according resources? Although I'm coding in PHP for quite some time now, this seems like basics I'm lacking..

Comment: @DevelJoe [https://php.net/require](https://php.net/require).

Comment: True it's actually written there, never really noticed that. I'm really impressed that I've never had this issue so far, cheers mate ^^

Answer (score 1):

I found the same error, but I had run the `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` install command from my DOS command line to install on my Windows environment before it got auto-deployed via PHPStorm onto a linux server - so the software files were deployed, but the adjusted autoload_psr4.php file didn't go with that - so that was the problem.

To fix, I had to do an additional install on my [auto-deployed] linux machine too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use composer to access PHPMailer files, you are most likely to encounter this issue. To resolve it, open the file

```
path-to-your-project/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php
```

and disable/remove the line that has

```
namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

It should be at the top before the class function begin. In my version `PHP Version 5.5.` it on line 22

Good luck!